# C++ Win32 Creating a Popup Menu From Resource

Tags: c++, winapi, menu, resources, popup

[image: Here is what it is doing]

I am trying to load a popup "right click" menu, and use the resource file to define the menu items. The picture shows what is happening when I right click, it displays room for 2 items, which is correct, but doesnt show any text.

In the .cpp:

```
POINT pt;
pt.x = LOWORD (lParam);
pt.y = HIWORD (lParam);
ClientToScreen (hwnd, &pt);
HMENU hMenu = LoadMenu(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_POPUPMENU));
TrackPopupMenu (hMenu, TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, pt.x, pt.y, 0, hwnd, NULL);
```

and the resource:

```
IDR_POPUPMENU MENU DISCARDABLE 
BEGIN
MENUITEM "test",              IDM_TEST
MENUITEM "Close",               IDM_CLOSE
END
```

any idea on what I am donig wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT: I just tested, and clicking in the "no text displayed" areas, and it sends the correct message. What could be causing it to not display the text?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
HMENU hMenu = LoadMenu(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_POPUPMENU));
hMenu = GetSubMenu(hMenu, 0);
```

and resource:

```
IDR_POPUPMENU MENU DISCARDABLE 
BEGIN 
   POPUP "TEST" 
      BEGIN     
        MENUITEM "Test",                IDM_TEST
        MENUITEM "Close",               IDM_CLOSE
      END
END
```

Just had to start the resource entry with a beginning sub menu, TEST does not display, only its menu items do.

Comment: SO is the real WinAPI documentation

Answer (score 5):

Your menu resource is incorrect. It must be a `popupmenu`.
eg:

```
IDR_MENU_TRAY MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "ContextMenu"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "ShowWindow",                  ID_POPUP_SHOWWINDOW
        MENUITEM "Exit",                        ID_POPUP_EXIT
    END
END
```

`TrackPopupMenu` first parameter is a handle to a submenu associated with an existing menu item.
You can see the examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms647558(v=VS.85,d=hv.2).aspx